# When upgrading from MVC 4 to 5 every razor call is beeing underlined and with an error message associated with it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When upgrading from MVC 4 to 5 every razor call is beeing underlined and with an error message associated with it.

The pages still works but it would be nice to have error messages removed and if the intellisense could start working again.

I'we read that using following could help but it don't.

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be different reason such as versions of refrenced assemblies to setting in Web.config.
Make sure that you didn't miss a step from this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

and this link also might help

http://ctsoftr.com/upgrading-from-asp-net-mvc-4-to-5/